# Autoproject several sequences into the main ViewModel via Automapper

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, automapper, automapper-2

I'm trying to auto project from SQL server with Automapper some data into my view models.

The view model I have is:

```
public sealed class WorkstationViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OccupiedByName { get; set; }
}
```

And the code I'm trying to use is:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Workstation, WorkstationViewModel>()
  .ForMember(T => T.OccupiedByName, T => T.MapFrom(W =>
    W.Sessions.AsQueryable().Select(E => E.StaffMember.Name).SingleOrDefault()));
```

Two properties `Id` and `Name` are auto-projected as they have equal names in `Workstation` class.

The exception I get on some codelines like this

```
var model = WorkstationsRepository.GetAll().Project()
           .To<WorkstationViewModel>().SingleOrDefault();
```

is some weird `object reference is null` exception and on the top of the stack trace there are some automapper's `CreateExpression<>` methods which gives me a conclusion that the automapper cannot generate a good one expression to translate it to SQL code.

When I use simple maps, like `.Name` to `.Category.Name` or other one-item retrievals from the SQL table, it works perfectly. All I need is to get access to **multiple** items while projecting the sequence via Automapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer `Project().To()` API takes a totally different route than the "classic" `Mapper.Map()` API. I think that the latter would run in your case, but of course you won't have the benefit of the projection trickling thought to the SQL.

During `Project().To()` AutoMapper tries to get `MemberInfo`s (reflection) from the involved types, which it uses to create lambda expressions. This means that the source properties in a mapping must be members of the source type. Evidently, `W.Sessions.AsQueryable().Select(...` is not a member of `Workstation`. So somewhere along the line AutoMapper bumps into a `null` memberinfo.

So, `Project().To()` is a bit restricted. In this particular case a remedy may be to map a `Session` with its parents `WorkStation` and `StaffMember` to the model. Reference navigation properties will map OK with `Project().To()`.